# Download Progress bar from Firebase Storage

Tags: unity, unity-networking

Im trying to make a progress bar based on downloaded images from Firebase storage, now firebase does provide a snipper which works per image

```
// Create local filesystem URL
string localUrl = "file:///local/images/island.jpg";

// Start downloading a file
Task task = reference.GetFileAsync(localFile,
    new StorageProgress<DownloadState>(state => {
        // called periodically during the download
        Debug.Log(String.Format(
            "Progress: {0} of {1} bytes transferred.",
            state.BytesTransferred,
            state.TotalByteCount
        ));
    }), CancellationToken.None);

task.ContinueWithOnMainThread(resultTask => {
    if (!resultTask.IsFaulted && !resultTask.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log("Download finished.");
    }
});
```

but i would like to make that appear on a UI text based on the percentage of the Bytes downloaded like starting from 0 to 100%.Now i have come to this function so far which does work in the sense of downloading from storage and i do get the percentage in the console but im not sure how to convert that to a percentage to show on UI.

```
        if (CheckConnectivity) //if the device is connected to the internet, initiate download.
        {
           // Debug.Log("Initiating download of: " + platform + _file);
            if (!File.Exists(localPath))
            {
            Task task = storageRef.GetFileAsync(localPath,
            new StorageProgress<DownloadState>(state => {
                    // called periodically during the download
                    Debug.Log(String.Format(
                "Progress: {0} of {1} bytes transferred.",
                state.BytesTransferred,
                state.TotalByteCount
            ));
            }), CancellationToken.None);

                await storageRef.Child(_child).Child(_file).GetFileAsync(localPath).ContinueWithOnMainThread(files =>
                {
                    if (!files.IsFaulted && !files.IsCanceled) //if download is successful.
                    {
                        Debug.Log("file saved as " + localPath);
                       
                    }
                    else //otherwise report error.
                    {
                        Debug.Log(files.Exception.ToString());
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("files Exist");
            }
           
        }
        else //otherwise don't bother.
        {
            Debug.Log("Cannot Download file due to lack of connectivity!");
        }
    }
```

in which case my debug is this

```
Progress: 1731 of 52804 bytes transferred.
```

Which i would like to say 0 % and counting up to 100!
Thanks!

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with unity-networking, firebase, or firebase-storage. :) Anyways. `(state.BytesTransferred / state.TotalByteCount) * 100 = %`. Google: "Unity UI progress bars".

Comment: thank you for the reply! i did try that but the debug was 0!
 var progress = state.BytesTransferred / state.TotalByteCount * 100f;
                Debug.Log(progress);
                percentage.text = progress.ToString();
Thats why i thought maybe it was something specific to networking!

Comment: Try `(float)state.BytesTransferred / state.TotalByteCount`

Comment: yea thanks it came to my attention that when dividing 2 integers it results in another integer 99/100 * 100 transfers into 0 * 100 because 99/100 is 0 . so i did it in reverse! 100 * state.BytesTransfered/state.TotalByteCount